# Android printing in kiosk mode

Tags: android, kiosk, google-cloud-print

I'm trying to build an Android application that will run in Kiosk mode. Guests will scan their tickets, and a name tag should automatically print for them with a welcome message on it.

I'm trying to do this using Google Cloud Printing. Right now I'm simply using the sample code from the official tutorial, and it works so far (as in, I can print documents and everything), but I have to run through two dialog pages:

1 to select the printer in question, and

2 to select the printing preferences.

Is there any way to skip these two dialogs? I would like the user to have as little interaction with the app as possible.

Comment: ever find a solution?